# Recive 2 emails, and dont know why

Tags: php, html, ajax, phpmailer

I inherited code, and now I have problem which I can not detected. When I fill up my form I receive 2 emails instead of 1. So if someone can help me and tell me why. 
My code is here: 
HTML:

```
<div class="container text-center forma-kontakt">

<form class="form-inline" id="upitForma" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group xx">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email2">Ime:</label>
        <input type="email2" class="form-control" id="upitIme" placeholder="Unesite Vase ime">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="ime2">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="upitEmail" placeholder="Unesite Vas email">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="ime2">Adresa Vašeg web-sajta:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="upitSajt" placeholder="Vaš web-sajt (opciono):">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group text-center" style="display:block">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-12 control-label text-center">Poruka</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message2" style="height:260px; width:600px"
                      id="upitMsg"></textarea>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>


    <input type="submit" id="upitBtn" class="btn btn-primary center-block" style="margin-top:20px; width:100px" value="Pošalji poruku">
    </input>
</form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
class Upit extends Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->view("upit/index", []);
}
public function upit() {
    if (isset($_POST['ime']) & isset($_POST['eMail']) & isset($_POST['poruka'])) {
        $ime = $_POST['ime'];
        $mail = $_POST['eMail'];
        $poruka = $_POST['poruka'];
    } else
        return 0;
    if (isset($_POST['listaUsluga']))
        $listaUsluga = $_POST['listaUsluga'];
    else
        $listaUsluga = '';
    if (isset($_POST['sajt']))
        $sajt = $_POST['sajt'];
    else
        $sajt = '';
    echo 1;

    $to      = 'example@mail.com';
    $subject = 'Upit kontakt';
    $message = "Novi kontakt od osobe: $ime (eMail: $mail ) \r\nPoruka glasi: \r\n $poruka \r\n\r\n Selektovana lista usluga: $listaUsluga\r\n\r\n $sajt\r\n\r\n !!! Ovo je automatska poruka, ne odgovarati na dugme REPLAY !!!";
    //$headers = 'From: example@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
        //'Reply-To: From: example@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
        //'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

}

}

?>
```

JS:

```
 $('#upitBtn').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myForm = $('#dugme');
    var anyBoxChecked = false;
    var i;
    var txt = "";
    var ime = $('#upitIme').val();
    var eMail = $('#upitEmail').val();
    var poruka = $('#upitMsg').val();
    var sajt = $('#upitSajt').val();
    $('#dugme input:checked').each(function(e) {
        //if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            anyBoxChecked = true;
            txt += " " + $(this).val();
        //}
    });

    var $myForm = $('#upitForma');
    if (!$myForm[0].checkValidity())
        $myForm.find(':submit').click();
    else
        e.preventDefault();
    var eMail = $('#upitEmail').val().trim();
    /*alert(eMail);
    alert(txt);
    alert(ime);
    alert(poruka);*/
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/upit/upit/",
        dataType: 'text',
        //data: {eMail:eMail, listaUsluga:txt, ime:ime, poruka:poruka, sajt:sajt}, 
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function(rez) {
        if (rez=="0") {
            $('#upitEmail').css({ "border": '#FF0000 1px solid'});
            $('#upitEmail').val('');
            $('#upitEmail').attr("placeholder", "Unesite ispravan mail!");
        } else {
            $('#upitEmail').val('');//TODO obrisati values i svih ostalih polja
            $('#modalBoxUspehUpit').trigger("click");
        }
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(ajaxOptions);
        console.log(thrownError);            
    });
    return false;
});
```

I don't know is this properly question, but I am stuck and don't know where is mistake. So all advice and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your button is of a type submit, so if its not stopped from processing(preventDefault) it will a) do an ajax request and b) process through to the action again. Are you absolutely sure that is not happening? I ask because I have never seen preventDefault used at the beginning of an event block :)

Comment: @NeilMasters I'm still beginner, and not good with Ajax, so I see preventDefault it first time, I assumed it was a mistake somewhere in PHP. And I am not sure at all, that is reason why I am here. It helping me in which direction to now. SO if you have some advice how to fix it, it is welcome. :)

Comment: you are not getting a large response because your problem is very difficult to replicate. I will take a look at this later today if its still a problem and try and replicate the bug.

Comment: Lets add a debug file. you must add a line every time that one mail is sent with date and time if possible, and look if the code runs once and you receive two mails, or if the code runs twice, and you receive one mail for each run.